# In 'X not to mention Y', is X a bigger benefit or Y is?

Tags: phrase-usage

I dreamed up the two sentences. I don't know that in 'X not to mention Y', whether X is a bigger benefit or Y is. Let's assume that increasing job prospects is a bigger benefit than building social networks. In this case, should I use Sentence 1 or Sentence 2?

> 1. Higher education offers an environment to build important social networks, not to mention increases job prospects.

> 2. Higher education increases job prospects, not to mention offers an environment to build important social networks.

Comment: I think ***not to mention*** works much better when what doesn't need to be mentioned (but is in fact *about to be* mentioned anyway! :) is a ***thing***, rather than a finite verb clause like ***increases** job prospects*. It's normally used in such a way that the verb associated with the first object (***offers***, here) applies to the "wasn't going to be mentioned" second object as well, so it can be "deleted", giving *Higher education offers **an environment to build important social networks**, not to mention **improved job prospects***.

Comment: In the first example you need to change "increases" to "increased". In the second change "offers" to "offering".  The X and Y elements used in this idiom need to be noun phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idiomatic construction does not necessarily mean that the mentioned matter is *bigger* than the unmentioned one - merely that it is sufficiently important that there should be no need to make a second point.

It can be used to refer to reasons *against* something as well as *for* it, so it isn't always about weighing benefits - it can be 'pros' or 'cons'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you mean both of my sentences make sense?

Comment: Agreed. Unlike "let alone", where the second thing must be of greater import, I don't see this as instantly requiring one ordering.

Comment: @newbieforever actually, your second example doesn't feel quite right... I think it's that you go into a fair bit of detail for the thing you "aren't mentioning". The unmentioned thing would normally just be a brief word or two, such as "better job prospects", or "development opportunities".

Answer (score 0):

The second item should be *at least* as significant as the first. In your case, if job prospects are more important, sentence 1 is more appropriate.

"Not to mention" doesn't necessarily imply a difference as extreme as similar phrases like "let alone," but it still loses some of its rhetorical impact when reversed.

Answer (score 0):

This can go either way. Usually, X is more immediately applicable to the subject at hand, and more specificially to the point.

"Using this gasoline will make your car run better, not to mention lower cost."

However, the construction can also be used ironically, when the less immediate aspect is also generally more important.

"Switching to solar power will lower your electricity rates, not to mention helping to save the planet."

So, there really isn't a yes or no answer to your question.