# an environment in which to build vs an environment to build

Tags: which

I wrote these two sentences. I forgot who taught me to use 'in which'. Can you explain what is the point of using 'in which' since the sentence is also correct without it?

> School provides an environment **in which** to build valuable social
> networks.

> School provides an environment to build valuable social networks.

Comment: I would consider 'in which' to be _necessary_, since things happen _in_ an environment.  Who told you the second version was correct?

Comment: @KateBunting, thank you.  I just assumed it was correct because no one pointed out it was incorrect in this question of mine: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/339441/in-x-not-to-mention-y-is-x-a-bigger-benefit-or-y-is/339488#339488

Comment: I suppose because that part of the sentence wasn't the issue being discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"School provides an environment to build valuable social networks" is theoretically ambiguous, but in this particular sentance the meaning is obvious. In spoken english it would be more common than using "in which", which might even sound a bit mannered. When written, though, it would be considered sloppy, even if the meaning was clear.